# Getting an error while saving file(image) to firebase storage in Node.js that is TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am sending the Bio Interests and ProfilePicture in body of my request and wants to save those in my firestore database, Bio and interests have no problem in that, but profilePicture Blob is giving me error while saving it to the storage bucket.

this is my userController.updateProfile function

```
exports.updateProfile = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { bio, interests, profilePicture } = req.body;
    const user = req.user;

    const bucket = STORAGE.bucket();
    const folderPath = `users/${user.uid}`;
    const fileName = `profile_image_${user.uid}.jpg`;
    const file = bucket.file(`${folderPath}/${fileName}`);

    await file.save(profilePicture._data, { // probably here is where I am getting the error
      contentType: profilePicture._data.type,
    });

    const imageUrl = await file.getSignedUrl({ action: 'read', expires: '03-01-2500' });

    await AUTH.updateUser(user.uid, {
      photoURL: imageUrl,
    });

    const userRef = DB.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
    await userRef.update({
      bio: bio,
      interests: interests,
      profilePicture: imageUrl,
    });

    return res.status(200).json({
      userUpdated: true,
    })

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
}
```

this is my updateProfile function form my clientside where i am making the request to this API endpoint.

```
const updateProfile = async () => {
    if (interests.length === 5 && bio.length > 0) {
      try {
        setLoading(true)
        const idToken = await FIREBASE_AUTH.currentUser.getIdToken();
        const encryptedIdToken = encryptData(idToken, SECRET_KEY);
        const encryptedBio = encryptData(bio, SECRET_KEY);
        const encryptedInterests = encryptData(JSON.stringify(interests), SECRET_KEY);

        // creating a blob out of an image and if user did not select any profile picture
        then it will be null but i am selecting the profile image each time        
        let blob = null;
        if (profileImage) {
          const ImageResponse = await fetch(profileImage);
          blob = await ImageResponse.blob();
        }
        const response = await fetch('http://10.0.2.2:5000/users/update', {
          method: 'PUT',
          credentials: 'include',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + encryptedIdToken,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ bio: encryptedBio, interests: encryptedInterests, profilePicture: blob })
        })
        const data = await response.json();
        if (response.status === 200 && data.userCreated) {
          setLoggedIn(true);
        }

        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        setLoading(false)
        throw new Error(error)
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

and this is my profile picture variable(I have logged that in my console), I created the blob out of it on the client side then send it to the server.
[image]

and this is the error which I am facing (sorry for my hiding my folder names I don't want to reveal my unique concept app idea don't mind it please)
[image]

Comment: What data type is `profilePicture`? If that's the file itself, you just might not need the `._data` part.

Comment: it is an blob I created on the client side and then send it to the server, and i tried using it without ._data but it creates the same problem, i have added my profile picture variable to the question please have a look at that.